# Multiple dispatch in componentWillMount React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two methods in two different actions,

```
import { fetchCategories } from "../../../actions/elementsActions"
import { fetchPlaces } from "../../../actions/placesActions"
```

And the componentWillMount method is:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchCategories())
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPlaces())
}
```

I want to make sure fetchCategories is fetched before fetchPlaces. Is this the right way of doing it?

**UPDATE**

Actions:

```html
import axios from "axios";

export function fetchPlaces() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get("/getPlaces")
      .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES_REJECTED", payload: err})
      })
  }
}
```

Reducer :

```js
export default function reducer(
    state={
        places: [],
        fetching: false,
        fetched: false,
        error: null,
    }, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case "FETCH_PLACES": {
        return {...state, fetching: true}
      }
      case "FETCH_PLACES_REJECTED": {
        return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
      }
      case "FETCH_PLACES_FULFILLED": {

        return {
          ...state,
          fetching: false,
          fetched: true,
          places: action.payload,
        }
      }
    }

    return state
}
```

Store :

```js
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux"

import logger from "redux-logger"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"

import reducer from "./reducers"

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())

export default createStore(reducer, middleware)
```

Comment: I believe dispatch is synchronous by default so yes it should work. However, setting state may not always be. Have you tried running your code to see if it works?

Comment: @KeithA Yes, in the componentWillReceiveProps, I'm checking if the nextProps has both the values and then setting the state.

Comment: Do you mind posting the action creators and the reducer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dispatch is synchronous, but this will only guarantee that `fetchCategories` is fired (not fetched) before `fetchPlaces`. You need to remove `this.props.dispatch(fetchPlaces())` from `componentWillMount()` and add it inside the `then((response)` of `fetchPlaces()` to guarantee that it fires after a successful fetch of `fetchPlaces()`.

Comment: Thanks @Rami Enbashi.